# Build an array of ids of all select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert a bunch of select boxes to be editable using the fantastic jQuery plugin: https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select.

The first step is to get the ids of all select boxes. From http://jsfiddle.net/49rk6ph7/69/ I have tried this but I'm not getting:

```
[s1,s2]
```

How can I get this working?

```js
var test = [];
test = $("select").each(function() {
  test.push($(this).attr('id'))
});

console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-editable">
  <select id="s1" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="format" value="" />
</div>

<div class="select-editable">
  <select id="s2" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="format" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is because you're assigning `test` to the result of `each()`, which is a jQuery object, not the array you originally define. Simply remove `test =` from that statement.

Note that you can also make the logic more succinct by using `map()` instead of an `each()` loop and by removing the outdated `on*` attributes with unobtrusive JS event handlers. Something like this:

```js
var test = $("select").map(function() {
  return this.id
}).get();

console.log(test);

$('#s1, #s2').change(function() {
  $(this).next().val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-editable">
  <select id="s1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="format" value="" />
</div>

<div class="select-editable">
  <select id="s2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="format" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Just for my understanding , with var test = $("select") , is test a jquery object?

Comment: That's right. In your original code `test` will be the value returned from `each()`, which is a jQuery object containing the `select` element. In the above it will be an array of strings returned from `.map().get()`

Answer (score 5):

Remove `test =` before your jQuery call. You’re overwriting your original `test` array.

This is all you need:

```
var test =  [];

$("select").each(function() {
    test.push($(this).attr("id"));
});

console.log(test);
```