# 'Mapping' jquery plugin function to multiple DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert a bunch of select boxes to be editable using the fantastic jQuery plugin: https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select.

The first step is to get the ids of all select boxes. I was able to get help [Build an array of ids of all select boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572341/build-an-array-of-ids-of-all-select-boxes) to get a list of the applicable select box ids.

Now I need to 'map' the jquery plugin function to the array of ids. To use the plugin the basic command is:

```
$('#editable-select').editableSelect();
```

I've tried:

```
 var test =  [];

$( "select" ).each(function() {
    test.push($(this).attr('id'))
});



$( "select" ).each(function() {
    test.push($(this).attr('id'))
});

  test.each(function() {
    $(this).editableSelect();
});
```

How can I 'map' the plugin function the the appropriate select box DOM elements ?

Comment: test.each is not a function. You can use test.forEach(). Also, I recommend you use the parameter to get your element. Like: `test.forEach(function(el) { el.editableSelect();} );`
Also, why you have 2 times the same code `$("select").each(func....`?

Comment: If you don't want to reuse your array, I think that `$( "select" ).editableSelect()` could work. I don't know this plugin, but often, when you call a function from jquery, it's done for every matched elements.

Comment: Sorry did not work. Based on http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/, it appears to need an id to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work...

```
$('select').each(function() {
    $(this).editableSelect();
});
```

... but after having a look at the plugin, it doesn't require the selector to get just one jQuery object (makes total sense), so it's even easier...

```
$('select').editableSelect();
```

... both options work, but obviously the second is the way to go. Here you have a fiddle with an example...

https://fiddle.jshell.net/1cuy7gsg/

*NOTE*: `.each()` is a jQuery function that can only be applied to jQuery objects. That's why you can't apply it to your `test` javascript array (`test.each` can't work).

I hope it helps

Comment: Sorry did not work. Based on http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/, it appears to need an id to be selected.

Comment: @user61629 Yes, it works... https://fiddle.jshell.net/1cuy7gsg/ And after having a look at the plugin, you don't even need the `.each()` (it also works, but you don't need it). I've edited the answer. Are you applying this inside of a `$(document).ready()` function? Are you getting any console error?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your looking at this. My use case is a little more complicated. I'll repost a more advanced question. I was trying to boil it down to a simpler question.